# Binary Search/Insert Methods not inserting correctly

Tags: java, database, sorting, insert, binary-search

I need to have a Student database that is sorted alphabetically, so I decided that I would keep the students sorted by inserting them correctly. So I decided to implement a binary search with an insert method to keep it sorted as it inserts.

However, for some reason it inserts incorrectly, and the database is no longer sorted. I know it has something to do with my logic with the .compareToIgnoreCase() method. Here is my code:

```
private Student[] binaryInsert(Student student, int min, int max) {
    int mid = (min + max) / 2;
    if (min > max) {
        return insert(studentDatabase, student, -1);
    }
    if (min == max) {
        if (studentDatabase[mid].compareToIgnoreCase(student)) < 0) {
            return insert(studentDatabase, student, mid + 1);
        } else {
            return insert(studentDatabase, student, mid - 1);
        }
    } else if (studentDatabase[mid].compareToIgnoreCase(student)) < 0) {
        return binaryInsert(student, mid + 1, max);
    } else {// last possibility: a[mid] > x
        return binaryInsert(student, min, mid - 1);
    }
}

public Student[] insert(Student[] database, Student object, int i) {
    Student[] newDatabase = new Student[database.length + 1];
    if (i == -1) {
        for (int j = 1; j < newDatabase.length; j++) {
            newDatabase[j] = database[j - 1];
        }
        newDatabase[0] = object;
    } else {
        for (int x = 0; x < i; x++) {
            newDatabase[x] = database[x];
        }
        newDatabase[i] = object;
        for (int x = i + 1; x < newDatabase.length; x++) {
            newDatabase[x] = database[x - 1];
        }
    }
    return newDatabase;
}
```

And My Input:

```
STUDENT/NAD86/RAFAEL/NADAL/1986/SPAIN
STUDENT/DJO87/NOVAK/DJOKOVIC/1987/SERBIA
STUDENT/FED81/ROGER/FEDERER/1981/SWITZERLAND
STUDENT/STA86/ALEX/STAIRS/1998/AMERICA
```

And my output

```
FED81: ROGER FEDERER, 1981, SWITZERLAND, 0.0
DJO87: NOVAK DJOKOVIC, 1987, SERBIA, 0.0
NAD86: RAFAEL NADAL, 1986, SPAIN, 0.0
STA86: ALEX STAIRS, 1998, AMERICA, 0.0
```

FED81 is the problem child. If I rearrange the input around, it does work, but I can't do that.

Thanks for the help in advance!

EDIT: It should be noted that I tried the same process, but with integers, and it worked in all of my tests.

Comment: what `studentDatabase[mid].compareToIgnoreCase(student)` is suppose to do? are you comparing string with object?

Comment: `insert(studentDatabase, student, mid - 1);` should be `insert(studentDatabase, student, mid );` as the insertion point _before_ `a[i]` is at `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Joop Eggen, I was able to get it working. The solution was to take out the "- 1" from the `insert(studentDatabase, student, mid - 1)` method call.

The fix was due to the fact that the insertion point before a[i] is at i, not i - 1.

Credit to Joop Eggen!